# Problems with Localization in xcode 4.5.2

Tags: xcode, cocoa, localization

I looking for help in Localizing a project.

Compiling on 10.7.x with xCode 4.5.2 - native Language is English.

I've added Localization to my project ( Localizable.strings,  ect.) but have found that the app will only display the English Key values while running on 10.7.x but will correctly display the system Language key vales while running on 10.6.x.

To see where my app is loading it's resource I've added in the code:

```
NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable" ofType:@"strings"];
NSLog(Path);
```

But on a Mac running 10.7.x the output is:

```
 .app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
```

This is the output regardless of what the system language is set to.

However on a Mac running 10.6.x the correct resource will load
with system language set to German the output is:

```
 .app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/Localizable.strings
```

with system language set to English the output is:

```
 .app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
```

I am completely stumped.. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

p.s..  I also compiled on 10.6.8 with xcode 4.2 and exact same results.